# TDD - 100% Coverage for methods that wrap SQL

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've just finished reading "Professional Test-Driven Development with C#" and have been trying to find a way to achieve 100% coverage in my code.  It's all good until I hit a repository class that is filled with methods implemented something like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<MyDataContract> LoadConditional(bool isCondition)
{
   const string QUERY = @"SELECT ...fields... FROM MyData WHERE [IsCondition] = @IsCondition";
   return DataAccessor.ReadMyContracts(QUERY, isCondition); // something, something...
}
```

I've been thinking about this for some time, and have not been able to find an answer on the internet that answers this question directly.

- I read things that would suggest that SQL related business would exist in another assembly.  I don't require this though and don't believe I should have to go there.  And this, from a code coverage, perspective is a pretty superficial change.
- I've read that you can hook up databases for your unit tests (which I've done before).  But this just well...  I dunno, it doesn't feel right.  The tests are slow and have a significant increase in maintenance.

My gut feeling is that without the last bit I mentioned, this method can't be unit tested.  How should I be viewing this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let me say that I believe that achieving 100% coverage makes no sense at all and doesn't prove anything.

That being said, I typically use some layer between DB and business logic - some simple mapper (PetaPoco, Dapper, OrmLite) or, rarely, a full blown ORM (NHibernate).

In cases where I need integration tests against a DB, these tools allow me to run the same queries against a test DB (e.g. an in-memory SQLite DB) instead of 'real' DB server.

With regard to your concern that "the tests are slow and have a significant increase in maintenance." you should bear in mind that these are not unit tests anymore - these are integration tests and they can't be as fast as unit tests.

Comment: I agree. Check out http://rickardnilsson.net/post/2013/01/19/how-to-unit-test-your-database-code-when-using-servicestack-ormlite.aspx for an example on how to do this.

Comment: Great example. And +1 for using ServiceStack :)

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.  "This is an integration test" says it all I think.  This is one of those moments where the tools and the hype constantly seem to suggest that I should be able to achieve this.  It's hard not to think, what am I not getting about this?

Comment: Good news is that nothing is wrong with you :) there is a lot of hype around TDD and unit testing, like this recent discussion: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/listen-to-trivial-tests and rebuttal: http://blog.markrendle.net/2013/03/09/dont-unit-test-trivial-code/ . Or http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/03/05/TheStartUpTrap.html and http://codeofrob.com/entries/uncle-bobs-viewpoint-considered-harmful.html

Comment: Ploeh is great.  Thx for the links!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, if you do actual data access, you are going in to integration testing and leaving the realm of unit testing. I personaly prefer to keep SQL inside the data access layer only, i.e. a single layer before the DB itself and then I test everything up to that point. In my view a method named `ReadMyContracts` should already have the correct SQL for accessing the data and should only receive (and pass on) the `isCondition` parameter.

That`s just MHO.