# How to write integration test against database

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, integration-testing

Lets say I have a class like below.

I'm not sure how I would write a unit/integration test against it. Does it need refactoring?

Would it simply be to add an Add/Find method (which it would have in reality), call the Add in the test then call the Delete and then the Find?

```
public class Repository
{
    public void DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        var connstring = ""; //Get from web.config
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID = @ID")
            command.Paramaters.Add("@ID", id)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to point you to another question posted just minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340569/tdd-100-coverage-for-methods-that-wrap-sql/15340652?noredirect=1#comment21666041_15340652

Comment: Your proposal seems also OK to me, as an integration test for the repository. Add, then delete then check if it is still in the DB. However, I prefer to have integration tests around use cases, not classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion - write an Integration test for repositories (since you are using a framework for data access), unless there is more than CRUD that you are doing in the repository.

Add/Find are all individual Repository methods, and they need to be tested themselves.

I would recommend, use `Setup` to setup seed data, that you know you can act on. In this case, insert records into `Products` table.

Then Act: Call `Repository.Deleteproduct(<product id created in setup>)`

Assert that: Product created in setup is deleted (Query the database again to check).

If you are using an ORM, this test would also test your mappings for Product.

Answer (score 2):

The golden rule is not to test framewkrk's code. Unless this method would have no custom logic there is nothing to test.
I think what you trying to achieve is to separate Repository to make unit-testing easy. The best way of doing this would be to create interface for your repository and mock it.
If you really want to create some integration tests then you have to create some test database where you could make your nuclear bombs experiments.

Answer (score 0):

I have never added unit test for database calls. This is definitely more of an integration test. There is nothing observable for you to check.

I know that Java had some tools for this that fitted into JUnit. IT requires that you write XML files that mimic before and after and then it compares the contents of the table to the XML file. I am sure that .Net will have something similar. However I am not sure that it is worth it. I found those tests to be incredibly brittle and provide very little value.

I would suggest take the pragmatic approach and don't write test for database objects. Rather test those object that interact with your database objects.